# Monero Helium Hydra - Segmentation Fault

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

I am running a clean install of Monero client for Linux 64bit, binaries as available on 13-oct-2017, v0.11.0.0

I have deleted previous client, and ~/.bitmonero.  I am importing an older wallet file though.

The blockchain synched for a few hours, but now whenever I run `monerod` it simply seg faults.

I have tried with `monerod --block-sync-size=1 --max concurrency 1` but it still just dumps with a segmentation fault.

Any advice on how to fix this?  Thankyou.

Comment: Could you help out w/ debugging? https://github.com/monero-project/monero#debugging

Comment: yes sure thing, very happy to help support monero. Just let me know what you need.  FYI I just compiled fresh from github and it is syncing.

Comment: Just FYI: tried a manual import of blockchain.raw before this, that too failed with error ``2017-10-14 00:46:55.545     7f727ffbe740 ERROR bcutil src/blockchain_utilities/blockchain_import.cpp:772 Exception at [Import error], what=Aborting``

Comment: do you want the stack trace from gdb?

Comment: ``Thread 22 "monerod" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffeccf6700 (LWP 16322)]
__memcmp_sse4_1 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcmp-sse4.S:1525``

Comment: Let me know if #2492 works for you. If not, please paste all relevant information (including gdb stack trace) to https://paste.fedoraproject.org.

Comment: Confirmed: resolves issue. Thankyou.  Suggest: this patch should make it into the publicly  available monero binaries as a matter of priority, to ensure a good end user impression.  Compiling from source while trivial for those who know, is in practice simply out of reach of the many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This crash was fixed in https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2492, and you can merge it to your tree with the following commands:

git checkout -b crash-fix
git fetch origin pull/2492/head:2492
git cherry-pick 2492

You're now on a branch with whatever source you had before, plus the crash fix. You can now compile normally.

When you want to get back to master (ie, to pull latest):

git checkout master

Comment: Thankyou.  FYI this crash occurs on the downloadable binaries from getmonero.org.  Confirming building from source with current master resolves the issue.

Comment: There will likely be a 0.11.0.1 soon to get those fixes in.